# Why is a macro "not declared in this scope" in my code?

Tags: c++, scope, macros, pi

I have googled to no end but have not found a definitive answer.

I use:

```
#include <cmath>
```

to include the `M_PI` macro (for the value of pi) in my header file.

I use `M_PI` in the class I have created in various functions, but when compiling on g++ I get the following error:

```
error: 'M_PI' was not declared in this scope
```

Why is this happening?

Given `M_PI` is a macro, why would it matter in which scope it is defined in? Doesn't the preprocessor simply replace every occurrence of `M_PI` with `3.1415926535...`?

Should I use a `constexpr` instead?

Comment: `M_PI` is not part of standard C++. However since C++20 there are [Mathematical constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants) in standard C++.

Comment: Since you're using gcc, have a look at `math.h` which is what `cmath` includes. `M_PI` is usually defined there (albeit not standard C++) and is guarded by some other `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `M_PI` in your code, eg

```
double x = M_PI;
```

Then the compiler does not know that you want to refer to a macro. It merely tries to find something called `M_PI` and doesn't find it. As you want to use it in this scope, the error complains that it is not declared in this scope.

It could be declared in a different scope, but then you cannot access it:

```
{
   double M_PI = 3;
}
double x = M_PI;   // M_PI is not declared in this scope
```

Note that since C++20 you can use [`std::numbers::pi_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was, however, using the M_PI macro and not the value of pi as a variable (in which case your answer would probably have fixed the issue). If you are interested, I posted a solution to my problem as an answer. Thanks for the help anyways!!

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl It shouldn't matter whether it's a macro or a variable.

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl  your question was about why the error complains about the scope. At least thats how I understood it. If `M_PI` is not declared then the compiler has no way to know if you meant the macro or some other `M_PI`.

Comment: Hi! Well, if M_PI is a macro, then the preprocessor simply replaces EVERY occurrence of M_PI with the value it holds (3.14159...), regardless of the scope that M_PI is found in, or where M_PI is defined. However, if M_PI were a variable and, say, declared within a function or an if statement, then, yes, it would only exist within that scope and would not be able to be accessed anywhere else.

Comment: sorry the last comment was for @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl sorry, you dont get the point, and I think I slightly misunderstood the quesiton. When `M_PI` is not declared then there is nothing to replace, then there is no way to know if it is a macro or not.

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl in C++ there is no `M_PI` in `<cmath>`. Actually I am not aware of a portable pi before C++20

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ah I see what you mean! Yes, sorry for misunderstanding your answer. Luckily, I was only using M_PI directly (not assigning its value to a variable). ```#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES``` seemed to work like a charm though!

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl I don't get your point. Again, for your code there shouldn't be any difference between `M_PI` (a macro) or `std::numbers_pi_v` (a global constant).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I believe there is, but it is, apparently, not defined by default, which is why ```#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES``` has to be included BEFORE the include clause of ```<cmath>``` or ```<math.h>```. I found this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/math-constants?view=msvc-170

Comment: there might be but it isnt standard C++ afaik, hence not portable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat cheers, never considered using ```std::numbers_pi_v``` before, I will now!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution.

Microsoft says that math constants in `<cmath>` (C++) and `<math.h>` (C) are not defined by default.

For them to be defined, you must define the following macro ABOVE the include clause:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
```

This fixed the problem I was having!